# Changing aspect ratio of Virtualbox VM under OSX

Tags: macos, virtualbox

I have a Windows guest on an OSX host, running at 1024x768.

I want to use scale-mode to make the window small enough to have on the side of my screen, but the problem is that since I maximised the VM in scale mode earlier, the aspect ratio is now nearer my 16:10.
I've tried resizing in only one dimension, disabling and re-enabling scale mode and also reinstalling guest additions.

A search of the [Virtualbox docs](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch14.html) does tell me that maintaining aspect ratio is doable under OSX, but it doesn't say how.

I'd really like to be able to fix this without reinstalling my VM if possible.

I'm running Virtualbox 4.2.16 r86992 under OSX 10.8.4 with a Window 7 guest.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/584807/8672) of mine about using `VBoxManage setextradata global GUI/MaxGuestResolution`, if it applies to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The aspect ratio of the guest screen is preserved when resizing the window. To ignore the
aspect ratio, press Shift during the resize operation.
User manual